# Prevent pagebreak when nesting environments

Tags: environments, page-breaking, nesting, expex

I have two nested environments, each for a different purpose, the first one is giving me a title. Unforuntately, although I have a `\nobreak` at the appropriate spot (I think) when I call the secondlevel environment right after the first, it doesn't prevent a pagebreak from occurring right after the title.

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{expex}
\newcounter{mycounter}[chapter]%
\renewcommand{\themycounter}{\thechapter.\arabic{mycounter}}
\newenvironment{firstlevel}{%
\par\addvspace{\medskipamount}%
\refstepcounter{mycounter}%
\noindent\textbf{Testing\ \themycounter}%
\par\nobreak\addvspace{\medskipamount}% << nobreak ignored
\noindent\ignorespaces
}{%
\par\addvspace{\medskipamount}\ignorespacesafterend\noindent
} 
\newenvironment{secondlevel}{}{} 

\begin{document}

Extraline to reach end of page

Extraline to reach end of page

\lipsum[2-6]

\begin{firstlevel}
\begin{secondlevel}

\lipsum[2]

\end{secondlevel}
\end{firstlevel} 
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{document}
```

How can I force `\nobreak` to be respected in this case?

(The secondlevel environment in the MWE is only a fake environment but in the real setup it does some important stuff which I cannot have the firstlevel environment do, as they don't always occur together.)

---

**EDIT:** 
Full disclosure, I'd need this not only in the above, but also in two other scenarios: one in which the next paragraph would start with a quote, as in `\begin{firstlevel}\begin{quote}Quote\end{quote}\end{firstlevel}`

This works with the above solution. But it also happens that the next paragraph starts with an `expex` example:

```
\begin{firstlevel}
\ex \begingl  \gla  Test  //
\glb  Test  //
\endgl \xe
\end{firstlevel}
```

In this scenario it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The page break is not ignored, it is just that you have introduces an all white paragraph just with a single line and no text and it is that line that is kept with the heading.

If you use

```
\par\nobreak\addvspace{\medskipamount}% << nobreak ignored
\noindent X\ignorespaces
}{%
\par\addvspace{\medskipamount}\ignorespacesafterend\noindent
}
```

then you will see

[image]

and if you omit the `X` the paragraph is still there, but harder to see.

If you use `\noindent` then the paragraph starts in the begin code of the environment so you can not start the environment body with a blank line or a list or any kind of display.

LaTeX never does this in the environments it defines, it would be better to define the enviornment using list and setting the environment using `\item` or as a heading. Both of which will prevent page breaks and optionally suppress indentation without using `\noindent` (internally they remove indentation using `\setbox` rather than use `\noindent`)

For example

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newcounter{mycounter}[chapter]%
\renewcommand{\themycounter}{\thechapter.\arabic{mycounter}}
\newenvironment{firstlevel}{%
\par\addvspace{\medskipamount}%
\refstepcounter{mycounter}%
\subsection*{Testing\ \themycounter}%
\par\nobreak\addvspace{\medskipamount}% << nobreak ignored
}{%
\par\addvspace{\medskipamount}\ignorespacesafterend
} 
\newenvironment{secondlevel}{}{} 

\begin{document}

Extraline to reach end of page

Extraline to reach end of page

\lipsum[2-6]

\begin{firstlevel}
\begin{secondlevel}

\lipsum[2]

\end{secondlevel}
\end{firstlevel} 
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{document}
```

Comment: That looks like it's getting me into the right direction, thank you!  Works in the above, but I have two slightly different scenarios where it still doesn't, for example if I do `\begin{firstlevel}\begin{quote}Quote\end{quote}\end{firstlevel}` I still have the title as the last line.  Is there maybe an even more robust approach, that would prevent the break no matter what the next part looks like?

Comment: I've clarified in the question the other two situations where I also use that environment.

Comment: OK, I had forgotten to get rid of the `\noindent` tag so with a `quote` environment it does work. Sorry, my bad!  But it does not work if what comes next is an `expex` example (see edits in the question). Any ideas why?

Comment: @jan I just tried adding your `\ex` instead of the `secondlevel` in this answer and it did not break after the heading  *testing 0.1* carried over to the second page

Comment: Remove one of the `Extraline to reach end of page` and the _testing 0.1_ will be the last line :(

Comment: BTW, if I substitute `\begin{firstlevel}` with `\subsection*{blah}` and then put the `ex`ample it'll have the same result, so I assume  `expex` somehow starts examples in a way that sticks an empty line above them which is then interpreted by the section command as a full paragraph ...

Comment: That problem is actually not related to this question (which your answer resolves perfectly), do you think I should ask a new question about expex?  (my hunch is it won't be easy to resolve)

Comment: @jan \def\lingexbreakpenalty{10000}%